# Where do I put my Django root dir in my Linux VPS

Tags: django, apache, vps

I have a VPS on which runs Apache. I created a simple html file just to test if my domain works on the internet and it works. This file is :

```
/var/www/html/index.html
```

But now I want to replace this by Django directories structure. Should I go in `/var/www/html` then run `django-admin startproject projectname` ?  I read somewhere in the official documentation that putting the site in /var/www is not a good security practice because people will be able to see the python code from the web...
I also would like to notice that I code the site on my laptop, not directly in the vps, so I host all the code on GitLab then I clone it from my vps, is it a good practice ?

Comment: So why don't you just clone it?

Comment: yes but where do i clone it to make the site available on my domain name

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/

Comment: put it anywhere you want, but make sure that your Apache configuration doesn't allow listing (and viewing) of the files in the directory where you put it. /var/www/my-django-project/ isn't bad practice as long as you check your Apache configuration. And yes, the correct way to deploy is to also use git on your production machine to clone/pull your source code.

Comment: How do I make my Apache configuration forbid listing and viewing the files ?